# Let A be a ring. Rewrite ${(x+1)}^5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(A,+,\times)$ be a ring for which 1 + 1 = 0 (0 and 1 are the neutral elements of it). Rewrite ${(x+1)}^5$ in terms of $x\in A$. I can't really work with rings and I don't know why... I do very well in compositions law and groups, etc.. but can't really understand what really happens in a ring...

Comment: The intuition for "what happens in a ring" during addition in multiplication is virtually no different than it is for integers. Modulo differences like the one I used in my solution...

Comment: Take an easy example of a ring, say $M_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$, or just $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Write out the expansion of $(x+1)^5$ as usual.  Then apply the fact that $1+1=0$   What is the value of $2x=x+x?$  What is the value of $3x$?  What is the value of $nx$ for an integer $n$?  Perhaps what you're missing is the convention that in any ring, $nx$ is the sum of $n$ copies of $x$ for any element $x$.

Comment: The ring may not be commutative, but this is not a problem here.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks, didn't look at it that way, say when I had: 10x^3 to write it as ((1+1) + (1 + 1) + (1 + 1) +....)x^3 and that would be 0

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde good point: we should just add that Restricting to the subring generated by $1$ and $x$, you’re back in a commutative ring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ring is an object which generalizes the integers (in that you may add and multiply objects). When $1+1=0$ has the property that $x+x=(1+1)x=0x=0.$ Using this fact, you can quickly show that $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1=x^2+1.$ You can then show that $$(x+1)^4=x^4+1$$ and you should use this to compute $(x+1)^4(x+1)=(x^4+1)(x+1)=x^5+x^4+x+1.$

Comment: Yup. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome. When you attempt these problems, you should make sure you know what rules you're allowed to use. I used the distributive property of rings for most of this argument. We're happy to provide you with references if you'd like as well.

Comment: I'd like some references! And some information about how to find the divisors of 0 in a ring? That would be really helpful!

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with ring theory, you should probably start with: http://abstract.ups.edu

Answer (score 4):

Using the [Freshman dream theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream) you have right away that $(x+1)^4=x^4+1$.

Then $(x+1)^5=(x^4+1)(x+1)=x^5+x^4+x+1$

Comment: That's a nice way to look at it but I didn't know freshman dream theorem. Nice theorem tho.

Answer (score 3):

If $1+1=0$ then effectively all even numbers disappear, and all odd numbers are $1$ (since $1 + 2k = 1 + k(1+1) = 1$). You can therefore multiply step by step, throwing out multiples of $2$ as you go, as shown in the other answers. Alternatively, if you know Pascal's triangle, then you can look at the row
$$1\quad 5\quad 10\quad 10\quad 5\quad 1,$$
corresponding to $x^5 + 5x^4 + 10x^3 + 10x^2 + 5x + 1$, then reduce modulo $2$ to get
$$1\quad 1\quad 0\quad 0\quad 1\quad 1,$$
so the resulting polynomial is
$$x^5+x^4+x+1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Just use the binomial theorem and replace every even integer by $0$ and every odd integer by $1$:
$$
(x+1)^5=x^5 + 5 x^4 + 10 x^3 + 10 x^2 + 5 x + 1 = x^5 + x^4 + x + 1
$$